# OpenJPA not numerical Id

Tags: jpa, openjpa

Is it possible to have a String Id in OpenJPA?

When I look at the documentation, it look's like it's possible, but when I try, I get this exception :

```
the given value "86272843-bb2b-4dd4-bb98-11195bbcf04f" cannot be converted into an identity for "class com.dooapp.infiltrea.model.SimpleEntity".  The value is the wrong type (java.lang.String).
<openjpa-2.1.1-r422266:1148538 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The given value "86272843-bb2b-4dd4-bb98-11195bbcf04f" cannot be converted into an identity for "class com.dooapp.infiltrea.model.SimpleEntity".  The value is the wrong type (java.lang.String).
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newObjectId(BrokerImpl.java:1278)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.newObjectId(DelegatingBroker.java:316)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:485)
at com.dooapp.infiltrea.model.io.ManagerIOImpl.read(ManagerIOImpl.java:112)
at com.dooapp.infiltrea.model.io.ManagerIOTest.testDelete(ManagerIOTest.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:35)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ClassLoaderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:103)
at $Proxy0.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:150)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireStarter.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bb2b-4dd4-bb98-11195bbcf04f"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:410)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
at org.apache.openjpa.util.Id.<init>(Id.java:109)
at org.apache.openjpa.util.Id.newInstance(Id.java:48)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.newDataStoreId(JDBCStoreManager.java:808)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.newDataStoreId(DelegatingStoreManager.java:156)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.newObjectId(BrokerImpl.java:1253)
```

I just have

```
@Id
String id;


@PrePersist
public void generateUUID() {
    this.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
}
```

When I remove String and put long instead, it work well, but it's not what I want.

Is this a bug on JPA, or am I doing something wrong?

Thank's

Comment: The stacktrace that you posted indicates that your @Id annotation is on a long field.

Comment: I'd suggest coming up with a unit test and posting it to the OpenJPA mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

OpenJPA allows you to choose uuid ids - [see here](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.0.2/apache-openjpa-1.0.2/docs/manual/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_gen)

Comment: Thank's for this answer, but as far as I understand the documentation, it's a generator to create UUID and put it into a String. Am I right?

Comment: I did :

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "uuid-string")
        String id;

But now my Id is always null.

Comment: strange. might be a bug, or a change in the new version of openjpa. I haven't used openjpa, but each JPA implementation has a generator like that.

Comment: I use the 2.1.1 version, and I think it's the last version :(